# To buffergeometry or not to bufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I am rendering voxel data based on [the approach described here](https://0fps.net/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/). Unfortunately he uses face4 quads which was deprecated a long time ago (r60). I am reimplementing it to use tris and while I was initially going to go for a bufferGeometry as there is a huge amount of triangles (500,000), there are also a large amount of overlapping vertices in the data.

It is my understanding that geometries can reuse verts but bufferGeoms cannot, so calling mergeVertices wont work. Will I get more of a speed advantage from bufferGeometry or the geometry class?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let anyone who may be interested know, I first created a geometry object and called mergeVertices. It worked well be started crawling for larger scenes. I converted it to bufferGeometry using `bufferVol = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(vol);` and managed to get a performance improvement.